# Spring-Boot - CSS Loaded not recognized fonts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, materialize

I'm experiencing spring boot, CSS and JS are loaded but fonts don't load (icons) I'm using [materialize CSS](http://materializecss.com/).

Here is the project structure :

```
resources
--static
----css
------materialize.min.css
----js
------materialize.min.js
----font
------material-design-icons
--------Material-Design-Icons.woff2, woff etc..
------Roboto
--------Roboto-... .woff, woff2 etc..
----images
```

Here is some lines of css loading fonts :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Material-Design-Icons";
  src: url("../font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.woff") format("woff"), url("../font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.svg#Material-Design-Icons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Here is the html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
          href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.css}"
          href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" href="../../static/css/main.css"/>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/materialize.min.css}" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>-->
    <title>Amazon project</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="sass.html"><i class="material-icons left">search</i>Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html"><i class="material-icons right">view_module</i>Magasin</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is html render : (no icon loaded, just writing icon asked)

Logo

```
search Accueil
view_module Magasin
```

I hope I didn't miss something.

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
   <version>0.1.0</version>

   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath/>
   </parent>

   <dependencies>
      <!-- SPRING BOOT START -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
         <version>5.1.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
         <artifactId>materializecss</artifactId>
         <version>0.97.5</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <!-- SPRING BOOT END -->
      <!-- Data access libraries start -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Data access libraries end -->
      <!-- THYMELEAF START -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
         <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
         <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <!-- THYMELEAF END -->
      <!-- BOOTSTRAP START -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.ars</groupId>
         <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- BOOTSTRAP END -->
      <!-- JAVAX START -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
         <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- JAVAX END -->
      <!-- HIBERNATE CORE -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
         <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
         <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- HIBERNATE CORE END  -->
      <!-- CSS -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
         <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
         <version>4.5.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- CSS END -->
      <!-- POSTGRESQL START -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
         <version>9.4.1207</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- POSTGRESQL END -->
      <!-- LOMBOK START -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <version>1.16.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- LOMBOK END -->
      <!-- JSON start -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.json</groupId>
         <artifactId>json</artifactId>
         <version>20141113</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- JSON end -->
      <!-- ANGULAR START -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
         <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
         <version>1.3.0-beta.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
         <artifactId>angular-ui-router</artifactId>
         <version>0.2.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- ANGULAR END -->
   </dependencies>

   <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <profiles>
      <profile>
         <id>springloaded</id>
         <activation>
            <property>
               <name>springloaded</name>
            </property>
         </activation>
         <dependencies>
            <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
               <version>${spring.loaded.version}</version>
            </dependency>
         </dependencies>
         <build>
            <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                     <agent>${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/springloaded/${spring.loaded.version}/springloaded-${spring.loaded.version}.jar</agent>
                     <jvmArguments>-noverify</jvmArguments>
                  </configuration>
               </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </build>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Try dropping the `..` in the `../font/material-design-icons/etc`.

Comment: It doesn't work :/

Comment: Open the `localhost:8080/font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.eot?#iefix` on browser. What happens?

Comment: Asking for username and password :O Unauthorized if I click on cancel.

Comment: Did you add the `spring-boot-starter-security` in your dependencies?

Comment: Not at all, I should ?

Comment: Add your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` to the question...it seems that you've enabled spring security